# Weighted Average SELECT Statement not working SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Script that creates a Database that tracks grades.

In one of my SELECT Statements which I use to display the class, Assignment #, Grade, Type... I want to also display the weighted average.

In the Grades TABLE I have a field that contains weight as an INTEGER. the Grade is also an INTEGER.

The code I use to create the TABLE is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE Grades
(
    entryID INT IDENTITY(1,1),
    classID INT NOT NULL,
    workID INT NOT NULL,
    workType INT,
    weight INT,
    grade INT

    CONSTRAINT GradesPK
        PRIMARY KEY (entryID)
)
```

I insert a sample record into it by using

```
INSERT INTO Grades
    (classID, workID, workType, weight, grade)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 3, 25, 80)
```

But when I try to run this SELECT Statement

```
    SELECT 
Classes.className AS 'Class', 
Grades.workID AS 'Assignment #', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Grades.grade) + ' %' AS 'Grade',
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Grades.weight) + ' %' AS 'Weight', 
schoolWorkType.workName AS 'Type', 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),((Grades.grade / 100) * (Grades.weight / 100)) * 100) + ' %' AS 'Weighted Average'
        FROM Grades
        INNER JOIN Classes
        ON Grades.classID = Classes.classID
        INNER JOIN schoolWorkType
        ON Grades.workType = schoolWorkType.entryID
```

I always get "0 %".

Is my equation wrong? Is there an issue with my Data Types? I am completely lost. I'm assuming it isn't Data Types as all the data being written to actual FIELDS are appropriate.

All help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Bryan

Comment: you want your weighted grade to be 25% * 80 = 20?

Comment: Yes, I even tried in a new Query with SELECT ((80 /100) * (25 / 100)) * 100 and it returned ZERO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Adam's correct answer, you can force decimal division like this:

```
SELECT  Classes.className AS 'Class' ,
        Grades.workID AS 'Assignment #' ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Grades.grade) + ' %' AS 'Grade' ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), Grades.weight) + ' %' AS 'Weight' ,
        schoolWorkType.workName AS 'Type' ,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), CAST((( Grades.grade / 100.0 ) * ( Grades.weight / 100.0 ) ) * 100.0 AS decimal(8,2))) + ' %' AS 'Weighted Average'
FROM    Grades
        INNER JOIN Classes ON Grades.classID = Classes.classID
        INNER JOIN schoolWorkType ON Grades.workType = schoolWorkType.entryID
```

I also casted to decimal before the convert to varchar to get rid of all but 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing integer division.  You need to convert those integers to decimals before the division.